# Что за ошибка Software caused connection abort: recv failed при приёме данных от клиента?

Tags: java

Добрый день, при приёме данных от клиента к серверу выскакивает ошибка Software caused connection abort: recv failed не могу понять в чём дело ?

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at Server.downloadFiles(Server.java:307)
at Server.logicFiles(Server.java:226)
at Server.connect(Server.java:117)
at Server.<init>(Server.java:83)
at Server.main(Server.java:67)
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeLong(Unknown Source)
at Server.logicFiles(Server.java:223)
at Server.connect(Server.java:117)
at Server.<init>(Server.java:83)
at Server.main(Server.java:67)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This error can occur when the local network system aborts a connection, such as when WinSock closes an established connection after data retransmission fails (receiver never acknowledges data sent on a datastream socket).". Глянь [этот MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832256.aspx). Также посмотри [информацию про 'Software caused connection abort'](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1689330).

Как правило, это означает, что произошла ошибка сети, такие как тайм-аут TCP

Answer (score 2):

[WINSOCK Error: Software caused connection abort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832256.aspx).

Обычно это говорит о неполадках в сети, например, TCP timeout. Попробуйте поснифать трафик на машине тем же wireshark, чтобы выявить проблему.

Попробуйте попинговать адрес.

Логи роутера посмотрите.