# Помогите найти ошибку в клиент-серверном коде

Tags: java

Коротко: две части программы - сервер и клиент (отдельные приложения).

Клиент:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
class Client {
    private String myName;
    private String myStatus;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    Message msg;
    public Client() {
        msg = new Message();
        myName = "yana";
        msg.setName(myName);
        myStatus = "doesn't matter";
        msg.setStatus(myStatus);
    }
    public static void main (String []args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setUpConnection();
    }
    public void setUpConnection(){
        try{
            System.out.println("start connection");
            Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            Thread t = new Thread (new Waiter());
            t.start();
            go();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void go(){
        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String text = null;
            while(true){
                text = sc.nextLine();
                msg.setText(text);
                msg.setDate(new Date());
                send();
                System.out.println("sent");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void send() {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(msg);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private class Waiter implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            try{    
                while(true){
                    Message inMsg = (Message) ois.readObject();
                    System.out.println(inMsg.getName() +" "+ inMsg.getStatus() +" "+ inMsg.getDate());
                    System.out.println(inMsg.getText());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Тут же класс для сообщений

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Date;
    public class Message implements Serializable{
        private String name;
        private String status;
        private String text;
        private Date date;
        public void setName (String n){
            name = n;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public void setStatus (String s){
            status = s;
        }
        public String getStatus(){
            return status;
        }
        public void setText (String t){
            text = t;
        }
        public String getText(){
            return text;
        }
        public void setDate (Date d){
            date = d;
        }
        public Date getDate(){
            return date;
        }
    }
```

Код сервера:

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;
    class Server {
        private ArrayList <Socket> clients;
        private ArrayList <Object> msgBuff;
        ServerSocket ss;
        public static void main (String []args) {
            Server server = new Server();
            server.go();
        }
        public class Clients implements Runnable {
            Socket sock;
            ObjectInputStream ois;
            public Clients(Socket sock){
                try{
                    this.sock = sock;
                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            public void run(){
                try{
                    while(true) {
                        Object m = ois.readObject();
                        tellEveryone(m);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    clients.remove(sock);
                }
            }
        }
        public void go(){
                clients = new ArrayList <Socket>();
                msgBuff = new ArrayList <Object>();
                try{
                ss = new ServerSocket(5000);
                while(ss.isClosed() == false){
                    Socket sock = ss.accept();
                    synchronized(this) {
                        printHistory(sock);
                        clients.add(sock);
                    }
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Clients(sock));
                    t.start();
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public synchronized void tellEveryone(Object message){
            renewHistory(message);
            ObjectOutputStream oos;
            try{
                for (Socket sock: clients){
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(message);
                    oos.flush();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private synchronized void renewHistory(Object message){
            msgBuff.add(message);
            if (msgBuff.size() > 10){
                msgBuff.remove(0);
            }
        }
        private synchronized void printHistory(Socket sock) {
            ObjectOutputStream oos;
            try {
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                for (Object msg : msgBuff){
                    oos.writeObject(msg);
                    oos.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
```

При попытке отправить сообщение, сервер выбрасывает исключение:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Server.tellEveryone(Server.java:84)
        at Server.closeServer(Server.java:115)
        at Server.access$1(Server.java:114)
        at Server$ComandListener.run(Server.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at Server.go(Server.java:64)
        at Server.main(Server.java:10)
```

Ругается на строчку oos.writeObject(message);

То есть, клиент отправляет данные, сервер их благополучно получает, но отправить обратно почему-то не может.

Если подключить нового пользователя, то история сообщений ему выводится, то есть метод printHistory() работает абсолютно нормально.

Comment: Отладкой пользоваться пробовали?

Comment: Честно говоря, нет. Я вот прямо такой очень начинающий "разработчик", который ей пока еще ни разу не пользовался. Точнее сказать, даже не знает что это и с чем едят.

Comment: попробуйте [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/191482), [Какие есть способы предупреждения ошибок, их нахождения и устранения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701817/191482)

Comment: Вообще [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546685/191482) написано, что "Как правило, это (Software caused connection abort) означает, что произошла ошибка сети, такие как тайм-аут TCP" и есть несколько советов что сделать

Comment: Да, в гугле это тоже основной ответ, но, учитывая, что я использую локалхост, я не понимаю, как какие сбои в сети могут выступать причиной. И, опять же, если подключить нового клиента, то сообщение, которое так и не отправилось методом tellEveryone() прекрасно отправляется методом printHistory()

Comment: Смущает в методе go добавление серверного сокета в клиентский список clients.add(sock); да ещё и потом запуск клиента с этим сокетом в отдельном потоке. Это возможно и правильно, но странно. Я бы посоветовал для отладки при создании серверного сокета в этом же коде сразу же поднять inputStrem из него (порт 5000), если вернётся null, то сокет явно не поднялся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема решилась добавлением явного приведения Message к десериализованному объекту:

```
m = (Message) ois.readObject();
```